# How to retrieve the runtime class of generics

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I'm about to generate an abstract class for DAOs, so I'm just wandering if it is possible to access generic type at runtime in method with signature `public Collection<ENTITY> search()`.

Please, this is the class :

```
/**
 *
 * @author Upgrade <Salathiel Genese, Yimga Yimga at salathielgenese@gmail.com>
 * @param <ENTITY>
 */
public class DAO<ENTITY extends Entity>
        implements DAOAware<ENTITY>
{

    @Override
    public void delete(ENTITY entity)
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public ENTITY save(ENTITY entity)
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public ENTITY search(Long id)
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<ENTITY> search()
    {
        return this.getSession().createCriteria(ENTITY.class).list(); // How to retrieve the runtime class of ENTITY
    }

    protected Session getSession()
    {
        return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

}
```

Comment: You can't do that.  Learn about type erasure.

Comment: You cannot unless you have a `Class<ENTITY>` variable somewhere.

Comment: You CAN do this, but it's hard.  Java doesn't like it.  There are various libraries to help you out if you must.  [Example.](https://code.google.com/p/gentyref/)

Answer (score 0):

Just to point out the obvious, if you have any type returned by this DAO, you can just call `getClass()` on it.

```
Class<?> type = dao.search( 1 ).getClass();
```

But this assumes you have an object or an ID you know will resolve to an object.

Comment: This will nottt let me know the rutime generic type, let say `Person implements Entity`, but output `java.util.Collection`

Comment: In you example code you showed that `search(int)` returns an ENTITY.  `search()` (with no arguments) returns a Collection.